# Example of a surjective submersion that is not locally a product?

Tags: differential-geometry

A surjective submersion $p:E \rightarrow M$ which is proper (compact sets of M have compact preimages) over connected $M$ is a fibre bundle ie has local products with a standard fibre.

If we drop the properness then presumably we lose the locally product structure; is there a nice concrete example to illustrate this?

(What confuses me is that submersions are locally projections which makes it look as though they ought to admit local products - but evidently not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the projection onto the $x$-axis 
$$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \} \to \mathbb{R}.$$ This is a surjective submersion of smooth manifolds but $\pi^{-1}(0)$, being disconnected, is not diffeomorphic to the other fibers.